# C and Objective C Cheat Sheets

Tags: objective-c

Im self learning Objective-C, and Im looking for some REALLY GOOD cheat sheets. Iv had little luck finding any. The one thing I would love to find is a list of, with syntax of Foundation Functions. Any luck?

Comment: If you are looking for a condensed http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html (Foundation Functions Reference) I still haven't seen a cheatsheet for that. Not sure why someone would need one either.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://maniacdev.com/2011/01/ios-developer-cheat-sheets/) lists a number of them.

Comment: I have been there but none of them provide a "Dictionary of Foundation Functions" with syntax. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in cheat sheet of sorts: Xcode will pop up an explanation window if you Option-click on a symbol in your code, which includes a link to the documentation and the header file.

Comment: @InnoProv: Wow, um, I thought I was just providing an alternative. Glad to be helpful! Don't forget to click the checkmark to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of Objective-C cheat sheets, along with almost any other language you can think of: http://www.cheat-sheets.org/#Objective-C